# Why do queries on two tables with the same structure have different execution times

Tags: postgresql, explain, time

I have partitioned a large table in a PostgreSQL database into monthly child tables with the same structure and similar numbers of rows. Recently I have noticed that the newer tables take much longer (up to 4 times as long) to run the same query, but I'm unsure why. They currently both have no indices and no discernable differences. I have run `VACUUM ANALYZE` on both tables, with no change in execution time.

The explain plans for each table running a simple query are as follows

```
c4billing=# EXPLAIN ANALYSE select distinct "LinkedAccountId" from c4102017;

QUERY PLAN                                                            

 HashAggregate  (cost=948388.67..948388.77 rows=33 width=13) (actual time=436086.651..436086.656 rows=35 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on c4102017  (cost=0.00..943718.29 rows=9340764 width=13) (actual time=187.460..432554.323 rows=8344050 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 436086.702 ms
(3 rows)

c4billing=# EXPLAIN ANALYSE select distinct "LinkedAccountId" from c4012017;
QUERY PLAN                                                           
 HashAggregate  (cost=829581.45..829581.55 rows=32 width=13) (actual time=257116.246..257116.253 rows=35 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on c4012017  (cost=0.00..825845.67 rows=7471557 width=13) (actual time=13.498..254204.195 rows=7470147 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 257116.284 ms
(3 rows)
```

I'd be very grateful for any insight or assistance!

Comment: What size does `\dt+` report for both tables?

Comment: c4102017 is 7156 MB, c4012017 is 6278 MB.

Comment: Are there other queries/processes running at the same time?  How reproducible is the timing difference?

Comment: Maybe table bloat. Try `vacuum c4012017` or even `vacuum full c4012017` - if that is a "newer" table it might have received more updates and deletes then the older ones.

Comment: Thanks both!! Vacuum analyze did absolutely nothing, but vacuum full seems to have done the trick! Queries are running 10 times faster now! Much appreciated!